# Postgres database migration "zero" downtime

Tags: postgresql

I have a setup with a JBoss EAP server, postgres 9.1 database. 
I will soon update so I have two JBoss servers in a cluster. This is mostly to avoid downtime when doing application deployments.

With the database as a single point of failure, how can I get close to zero downtime when having database migrations.

Comment: This seems like a good fit for dba.SE.

Answer (score 4):

> how can I get close to zero downtime when having database migrations.

Set up a streaming replica pair, with a master and a replica. Use WAL archiving in addition to streaming replication to deal with connectivity drops. Make sure your application is easily reconfigured to switch to a different server for if you need to fail over; if it's not easy to reconfigure, run a local [PgBouncer](http://pgbouncer.projects.pgfoundry.org/) on each node so you can switch it to connect to a different PostgreSQL without needing to mess with the rest of the server config.

A tool like [repmgr](http://repmgr.org/) makes this considerably simpler.

To learn more, read [the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/high-availability.html).